# Report lab double quotation marks

Tags: python, reportlab

---

I have a problem with a qutation mark in report lab. When data that needs to be shown contains only one double quotation mark report markup language reports error in syntax. When there are two double quotations mark in data its ok. Is there any way to allow display of data that contains only one double quotation mark?

Comment: Try escaping the quotes with a backslash?

Comment: But its dynamic data, its readen from variables, I dont know where exactly quotation marks will appear...

Comment: Can you show example strings that work and don't work? Also maybe some of the code where you're seeing this problem in case there is something more going on.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, problem is not with ", but with character &.I have two strings in data with & and when I remove them everything works fine. Error is: "Expected ; after entity name".  By the way, data is wraped in <para> tag.

Comment: Correct. & is used as an escape character. It's looking for escape codes just like you use in HTML: `&amp;`.

Comment: So I have to search my strings and replace & in strings with something like \&?